# Error when parsing XML from filesystem

Tags: xml

I am trying to load XML from filesystem in order to extract some values.
Here are my attempts performed so far:

```
DECLARE
  xmlClob CLOB;
  xmlFile BFILE;
  x XMLType;
  src_offset number := 1 ;
  dest_offset number := 1 ;
  lang_ctx number := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
  warning integer;
BEGIN
  xmlFile := BFILENAME('d:\xml_files', 'example.xml');
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(xmlClob, true);
  DBMS_LOB.FILEOPEN(xmlFile, DBMS_LOB.FILE_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.LOADCLOBFROMFILE(xmlClob, xmlFile, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, src_offset,
  dest_offset, DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_CSID, lang_ctx, warning);
  x := XMLType.createXML(xmlClob);
  DBMS_LOB.FILECLOSEALL();
  DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(xmlClob);
  FOR r IN (
   SELECT ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Subjekt/Zkratka/text()') as kod
         ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Subjekt/AdresaUradu/UliceNazev/text()') as ulice
         ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Subjekt/AdresaUradu/CisloDomovni/text()') as  cislo_domovni
         ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Subjekt/AdresaUradu/CisloOrientacni/text()') as cislo_orientacni
    FROM   TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(x,'/SeznamOvmIndex/Subjekt'))) p
   WHERE ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Subjekt/Zkratka/text()') = 'CUZK'
   ) LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(r.kod||' '||r.ulice||' '||r.cislo_domovni||'/'||r.cislo_orientacni);
 END LOOP;
 END;
```

but i am getting error:
22285. 00000 -  "non-existent directory or file for %s operation"
*Cause:    Attempted to access a directory that does not exist, or attempted
           to access a file in a directory that does not exist.
*Action:   Ensure that a system object corresponding to the specified
           directory exists in the database dictionary, or
           make sure the name is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `BFILENAME('d:\xml_files', 'example.xml');`
you must use an oracle directory like
`BFILENAME('INPUT_DIR', 'example.xml');`

Use

`select * from dba_directories;` to get a list of directories

and

`CREATE DIRECTORY INPUT_DIR AS 'C:\tempdir';` to create a directory.